# JS - When to apply the module pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I have a module "badges.js", where I just have two methods: "increaseBadge" and "resetBadge".

```
//
// badges.js
//
function increaseBadge(badgeType, userId, value) {}

function resetBadge(badgeType, userId) {}

module.exports = { increaseBadge, resetBadge };
```

Does it have sense to apply the module pattern in order to offer a clean interface? Should I use an IIFE or just export an object?

I mean, this

```
const badges = Object.freeze(
  VALID_BADGES_TYPES.reduce(
    (acc, badgeType) => (
      (acc[badgeType] = {
        increase: (userId, value) =>
          increaseBadge(userId, badgeType, value),

        reset: (userId) =>
          resetBadge(userId, badgeType),
      }),
      acc
    ),
    {}
  )
);

function increaseBadge(badgeType, userId, value) {}

function resetBadge(badgeType, userId) {}

module.exports = badges;
```

**VS** encapsulating all the logic with an IIFE (does it have sens? Since I am already declaring all this related stuff in a module)

```
const badges = (() => {
  function increaseBadge(userId, badgeType, value) {}

  function resetBadge(userId, badgeType) {}

  return Object.freeze(
    VALID_BADGES_TYPES.reduce(
      (acc, badgeType) => (
        (acc[badgeType] = {
          increase: (userId, value) =>
            increaseUserBadge(userId, badgeType, value),

          reset: (userId) => resetUserBadge(userId, badgeType),
        }),
        acc
      ),
      {}
    )
  );
})();

module.exports = badges;
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of `reduce` here.

Comment: I am just returning a dynamic object. ["badgeType1", "badgeType2"].reduce((acc, badgeType) => interface, {})

Comment: @Andy it's `.map()` with extra steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the revealing module pattern is to create a bundle of logic without polluting the global scope with variables that are used internally.

CommonJS modules have their own scope already, so there is no point in applying the revealing module pattern inside a CommonJS module.

Comment: I would say the module *system* is a formalisation of the module *pattern*. They both achieve the same thing. The modules system is more convenient as it relies on less code and implicitly works as needed.